# 33883 H-Bridge Driver IC Intermittent Switching

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, driver, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I am using a NXP (freescale) 33883 H-Bridge gate driver IC to drive a simple H4 bridge circuit which is connected identically to that in the application schematic in the datasheet:
[image]

I am switching at 25kHz using bipolar modulation and maintaining a duty cycle of 50 as it is being switched over a transformer. I am controlling the input signals with a STM32F4Discovery, which have an amplitude of 3V, which is sufficient according to the datasheet. Here are screenshots of both the input and output signals to HS1:
[image: 25kHz HS1 input signal at 3V]
*25kHz HS1 input signal at 3V*

[image: GATE_HS1 output signal]
*GATE_HS1 output signal*

[image: GATE_HS1 output signal zoomed]
*GATE_HS1 output signal zoomed*

You can see that it switches at the desired 25kHz for a short period of time before falling to zero and not switching again for another 3ms. I have used electrolytic capacitors for Clr_out and Ccp_out, but Ccp is a surface mount ceramic 33nF. Is there not enough charge stored in the capacitors to switch at the desired frequency? Is the 12VDC power supply which is rated at 1W not providing enough power to switch (33883 max power is 1.25W)?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

NB. Please ignore the pk-pk values on the oscilloscope, they are proportional to one another but not correct in amplitude.

Comment: What is connected to VCC2 (VBAT) ?

Comment: You should also use your oscilloscope to examine the 12 volt supply. To assure that it is stable at 12 volts.

Comment: Check your grounding. It is quite likely the motor current is raising the level of the ground to a point where the input signals from the micro are outside the logic level tolerances of the driver, especially if the micro is not really close to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this issue, it was the power supply. I connected the Vcc pin to a 12V benchtop power supply and it worked fine.